# Converting server date with Z format to local nsdate

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I need to convert this server date (Given from kinvey request) into local timezone.

I'm using the following code:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sTZD"
print(dateFormatter.dateFromString(newValue))
```

The date format is this:

> ect = "2016-08-28T16:30:06.553Z" or 
>           lmt = "2016-08-28T16:30:06.553Z"

When I print the date it is nil, do you know what I'm doing wrong ?. I think it could be the end of the dateFormat

Comment: The date string seems to be a simple UTC date, and you seem to be simply trying to parse it as an `NSDate`. What do you mean by ECT or LMT in the title?

Comment: Your right it'S a simple utc date, The issue is I cant parse It into a nsdate I just trying with a lot of formarters but neither works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your app can target only iOS7+, you can use format symbols described in:

[Fixed Formats (in Data Formatting Guide)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW13)

Unicode Technical Standard #35 [version tr35-31](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

> second | S | 1..n | 3456 | Fractional Second - truncates (like other
> time fields) to the count of letters. (example shows display using
> pattern SSSS for seconds value 12.34567)
>
> zone | X | 1 | -08,+0530,Z | The
> ISO8601 basic format with hours field and optional minutes field. The
> ISO8601 UTC indicator "Z" is used when local time offset is 0. (The
> same as x, plus "Z".)

So, to parse fractional second, use uppercase 'S',

and 'X' for timezone including "Z" as UTC.

Try this:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"
```

(I escaped 'T' as it may be used as another time formatting symbol in the future.)

---

PS. Though I couldn't have found a thread describing the date format which interprets "Z" as UTC+0000, ignoring or removing it may not be a bad solution, if some conditions met. Please find your best solution.

Comment: thank you, it finally works. Also I've implemented another solution by creating a new **substring** from the given **date**  deleting the last 5 characters and parsing it but I think your answer is the best solution.

Comment: why u replacing Z with X, but it did the magic can you explain on this

Comment: @ShivaPrasad, please check the [linked article](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns). Simply saying, formatting symbol `Z` matches date offset like **`+hh:mm`** (and some others), but it does not match **`Z`**. But formatting symbol `X` matches both **`+hh:mm`** and **`Z`**.